# Android Studio Bottom Navigation caused error

Tags: android-studio, bottomnavigationview, oncreate

**I dont know how to solve it i try too much but if i make a bottom navigation my app unfortunately stopped working after splash screen  plz help me**

**When i remove bottom navigation app works perfect but when i add bottom navigation it not works but i need to add bottom navigation How can i resolve this error**

**my xml code**

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="#00695C"
    app:itemTextColor="#00695C"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp"
    />
```

**My java file code**

```
    bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNav);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,new HomeFragment()).commit();


  `private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNav=new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment selected = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.nav_home:
                selected = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_chat:
                selected = new ChatFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_discussion:
                selected = new DiscussionFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                selected = new NotificationFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                selected = new ProfileFragment();
                break;

        }
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, selected).commit();

        return true;
    }
};
```

**MENU**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_chat"
        android:title="@string/chat"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
        android:title="Discussion"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_discussion"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notification"
        android:title="@string/notification"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:title="@string/profile"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

</menu>
```

**Error Shown in logcat**

```
07-05 01:24:26.822 5495-5514/com.example.appname E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider 

info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
07-05 01:24:26.823 5495-5514/com.example.appname E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found
07-05 01:24:26.830 5495-5514/com.example.appname E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found
07-05 01:24:27.591 5495-5515/com.example.appname E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.phenotype
07-05 01:24:32.340 5495-5495/com.example.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appname, PID: 5495
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paragonssoft.community/com.paragonssoft.community.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your bottomNavigationView?

Comment: BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;    //in the main activity

Comment: Can u plz help me

Comment: Make sure you are inflating the correct activity i.e. the one that has the bottomNavigation. also make sure you have initialized it properly i.e.
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewByID(R.id.bottomNav)

Comment: yes i do everthing properly and i initialize properly

Comment: Thanks i resolve it i have problem in intialize code